# C# StarTeam SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, starteam

I'm playing around with the StarTeam SDK at work, and whilst I can connect to our server, when it is connected, no projects are showing.

It gives an exception saying that `Borland.StarTeam.ServerUnavailableException`, although the `isConnected` value is true.

Anybody used this and can shed any light?

Thanks.

Comment: What i found about this exception: "This usually means that the server has been locked for backup by the StarTeam Administrator." :)

Comment: @Reniuz - yes that's what I found also.  Although I know it's not locked as I can access the server fine via the StarTeam client.

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the exception?

Comment: The starteam .Net SDK is free product or paid product?I am trying to download SDK from http://supportline.microfocus.com/ but it is asking for registration with a serial number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StarTeam .NET SDK is 32-bit only.  This is one of the possible errors that can come up when you compile your app for something other than x86 specifically.  Could that be the issue?

MicroFocus has been heavily rewriting the .NET SDK, so I'm hoping the documentation for problems like this gets better.

Comment: is the starteam .Net SDK free product or paid product?I am trying to download SDK from `http://supportline.microfocus.com/` but it is asking for registartion with a serial number.

Comment: They post their releases to their community forum: http://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/starteam/w/wiki/620.starteam-sdk-topics-releases.aspx  The downloads are available through supportline to registered users even if you don't buy anything (last I checked), but they are also usually available on the same ftp site they give to download the readme.  Try browsing this: ftp://stsdkcust:LpeEFPwNMJ@emeaftp.microfocus.com

Comment: Thank you Jeremy.i got the .Net SDK though the process took time.downloaded the trial version of StarTeam product then using that serial number i registered.After that micro focus support team sent the username and password.